# MongoError: No array filter found for identifier 'i' in path 'mainCourse.$[i].subCourse.$[j].ppt'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

MongoError:

> No array filter found for identifier 'i' in path

```
'mainCourse.$[i].subCourse.$[j].ppt'    
var qry3 = { F_id : req.params.F_id , "mainCourse.id" : req.params.MC_id };

db.collection('test').updateOne(qry3,{ $push : { "mainCourse.$[i].subCourse.$[j].ppt" : { pageid : pId , pagelink : link+'/ppt/'+fileName } } } ,{arrayFilters: [{ "i.id": req.params.MC_id }, { "j.id" : req.params.SC_id }]} , (e,r)=>{});

2nd try : 
db.collection('test').updateOne(qry3,{ $push : { "mainCourse.$.subCourse.ppt" : { pageid : pId , pagelink : link+'/ppt/'+fileName  }  } } , (e,r)=>{});

Error : MongoError: Cannot create field 'ppt' in element {subCourse: [ { name: \"COMP\", id: \"1\", imageLink: \subCourse/icon.png\", ppt: [], chapters: [] } ]}
 {
 "_id": "5c66b3918427a5032fc7eb85",
 "feild": "SW",
 "F_id": "66",
 "mainCourse": [
             {
              "name": "CI",
              "id": "1",
              "imageLink": "1.png",
              "subCourse": [
                       {
                        "name": "Comp",
                        "id": "2",
                        "imageLink": "2.png",
                        "ppt": [],
                        "chapters": []
                       }]
             }]
}
```

I need to Add(push) data in ppt Array. How can I do this?

Comment: would you please add your code

Comment: i am already mention check 3rd and 4th line what am i try for update

Comment: in Terminal working good ..... . but in nodejs not working  version :-"mongodb": "^2.2.34",

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solve there is problem in Nodejs Version

if using mongodb version "2.2.34" in nodejs side then use below syntex

mc and sc = which array position u need to store
var qry2= { F_id :req.params.F_id , mainCourse : { $elemMatch : { id :req.params.MC_id , subCourse :{ $elemMatch :

{ id :req.params.SC_id }
} } } }; // for my docment u can see in img
db.collection('test').update(qry2,{ $push : { ["mainCourse."+mc+".subCourse."+sc+".ppt"] : { pageid : pId , pagelink : link+'/ppt/'+fileName }
} });